# What's the equivalent of constructors in CLOS?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clos

How would you express the following Java code in Lisp?

```
class Foo {
    private String s;

    public Foo(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public Bar(int i) {
        super(Integer.toString(i));
    }
}
```

In Lisp, is `make-instance` or `initialize-instance` the equivalent of a constructor? If yes, how do you call the super class constructor(s)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `CALL-NEXT-METHOD` from within a method to call the next one.

Typically just use the standard method combination facility and write an `:BEFORE`, `:AFTER` or `:AROUND` method for `INITIALIZE-INSTANCE`.

One way:

```
(defclass foo ()
  ((s :type string :initarg :s)))

(defclass bar (foo) ())

(defmethod initialize-instance :around ((b bar) &key i)
  (call-next-method b :s (princ-to-string i)))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 17 > (make-instance 'bar :i 10)
#<BAR 402000B95B>

CL-USER 18 > (describe *)

#<BAR 4130439703> is a BAR
S      "10"
```

Note that I've called `CALL-NEXT-METHOD` without changing the argument it dispatches on. I just changed the `&key` initarg parameter.

Comment: Doesn't CALL-NEXT-METHOD just call the next method with the same arguments. How would I implement my example, i.e., converting the integer argument to a string and passing it to the super class method?

Comment: @Tobias Brandt: see my example

Answer (score 3):

Here is an amplification of Rainier's example that adds a small twist:
specialization (subclassing) by constraining slot values, at least at
construction time. Consider a class, *m-box*, for two-dimensional rectangles:

```
(defclass m-box ()
  ((left   :accessor m-box-left   :initform 0 :type integer :initarg :left  )
   (top    :accessor m-box-top    :initform 0 :type integer :initarg :top   )
   (width  :accessor m-box-width  :initform 0 :type integer :initarg :width )
   (height :accessor m-box-height :initform 0 :type integer :initarg :height)))
```

We can try it like this:

```
(describe (make-instance 'm-box :left 42 :top -39 :width 5 :height  11))

: #<M-BOX {10047A8F83}>
:   [standard-object]
: 
: Slots with :INSTANCE allocation:
:   LEFT    = 42
:   TOP     = -39
:   WIDTH   = 5
:   HEIGHT  = 11
```

Now consider a subclass or specialization: let an *m-block* be an m-box with
unit width and height. We set the *initialize-instance* method to pass through
values for *left* and *top*, but not *width* and *height*:

```
(defclass m-block (m-box) ())
(defmethod initialize-instance
    :around
    ((mb m-block)
     &key (left 0) (top 0))
  (call-next-method mb :left left :top top :width 1 :height 1))
```

We can make an instance of *m-block* as follows:

```
(describe (make-instance 'm-block :left 17 :top -34 :width 5 :height  11))

: #<M-BLOCK {10049C0CC3}>
:   [standard-object]
: 
: Slots with :INSTANCE allocation:
:   LEFT    = 17
:   TOP     = -34
:   WIDTH   = 1
:   HEIGHT  = 1
```

The constructor does not block the user's attempt to set *width* and *height*,
as it would do with some non-existent slot:

```
(describe (make-instance 'm-block :left 17 :top -34 :plugh 2345))

Invalid initialization argument:
  :PLUGH
in call for class #<STANDARD-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::M-BLOCK>.
   [Condition of type SB-PCL::INITARG-ERROR]
```

but the constructor *does* correct the user's invalid inputs with 1.

You might want to make the model more watertight by calling `error` if the
user attempts to input invalid *width* or *height*:

```
(defclass m-block (m-box) ())
(defmethod initialize-instance
  :around
  ((mb m-block)
   &key (left 0) (top 0) (width 1) (height 1))
  (when (or (/= 1 width) (/= 1 height))
    (error "an m-block must have unit width and height"))
  (call-next-method mb :left left :top top :width 1 :height 1))
```

The following attempt by the user is rejected:

```
(describe (make-instance 'm-block :left 17 :top -34 :width 5 :height  11))

an m-block must have unit width and height
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]
```

But this one, which also demonstrates defaulting of *height*, goes through:

```
(describe (make-instance 'm-block :left 17 :top -34 :width 1))

: #<M-BLOCK {1005377983}>
:   [standard-object]
: 
: Slots with :INSTANCE allocation:
:   LEFT    = 17
:   TOP     = -34
:   WIDTH   = 1
:   HEIGHT  = 1
```

This example allows the user to `setf` the width or height afterwards. I do not
know how to make the width and height *read-only* in instances of the subclass
and not in instances of the superclass.